# Remove spacing from \part?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, line-spacing, parts

[image: Current state of \part spacing]

Currently, trying to reduce the line spacing when I use the `\part` command. Ideally, I am currently trying to achieve the following result below:

```
Part I: Project Scope
```

With the surrounding padding reduced as much as possible. How do I go about achieving this in LaTeX as I've been using the evening to searching for an answer but can't seem to find the answer I need.

I currently have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \part{Project Scope}
  \section{Background}
\end{document}
```

Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you use `article` class, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \hskip1em
     \fi
     \Large \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
   \def\@spart#1{%
   {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \Large \bfseries #1\par}%
   \nobreak
   \vskip 3ex
   \@afterheading}
     \makeatother
\begin{document}
  \part{Project Scope}
  \section{Background}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\par\nobreak}{\hskip1em}{}{}
 \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\huge \bfseries}{\Large \bfseries}{}{}
 \xpatchcmd{\@spart}{\huge \bfseries}{\Large \bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \part*{Project Scope}
  \section{Background}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first example worked perfectly. Thank you.